# Can not authenticate via python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

Output file shows that POST-request works fine but the website still requires authorizing:

```
      import requests
      import sys
      def main():
          session = requests.session(config={'verbose': sys.stderr})

            login_data = {
            'email': 'PHONE_OR_LOGIN',
            'pass': 'PASSWORD',
            }

     r = session.post('http://vk.com/login', data=login_data)

     text_file = open("save.html", "w")
     text_file.write(r.content)
     text_file.close()
     print r.content

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but the website still requires authorizing" ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: check page in browser using DevTools in Chrome/Firefox - it sends login data to https://login.vk.com/?act=login and it sends not only `email` and `pass` but also other fields - and other headers - all can be very important.

Comment: I added hidden inputs:
        'act': 'login',
        'to': '',
        'expire': '',
        '_origin': 'https://vk.com/login',
        'ip_h': '9ef79a74fd031ff425',
        'lg_h': 'a4d324d9f8e957114f',
And header headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

But still can not authorize